# GRAILS URLMapping : "exclude" not working: href link for opening a file is returning 404 error from a gsp page

Tags: grails, gsp, url-mapping

This is a weird issue :

I have link on a gsp page which should open a pdf file named "fileInstruction.pdf" from a location "/appName/docs" where "appName" is the name of the application

the html on the gsp looks like :

```
   <div>
        <h6>File examples and instructions</h6>
        <a href="/appName/docs/fileInstruction.pdf" target="blank">File format instructions</a>
   </div>
```

But clicking the link seems looking for a controller and I am getting 404 error. The folder has the pdf file as I tried :

"file:///C:/applications/appName/docs/fileInstruction.pdf" opened up the doc on the browser.

Tried to exclude url mapping as:

```
 class UrlMappings {
   static excludes = ["/docs/*"]
    static mappings = {
           ....
     }
 }
```

Does not seem to work. I am using grails 2.0.1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make sure all your capitalization is correct. cross reference the file name with the `href`.. if its off, it will work locally but not online.

Comment: What is the path of the HTML file?

Comment: Issue is: instead of directly looking for the file, it's trying to go through a controller

Comment: **This is the path of the file(development): file:///C:/applications/appName/docs/fileInstruction.pdf and path of the file(production): https://hostName/appName/docs/fileInstruction.pdf**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root directory of your application isn't the root for URLs, web-app is. Move it to `C:/applications/appName/web-app/docs/fileInstruction.pdf` and remove the changes in UrlMappings.groovy since that has nothing to do with static resources, only controller-based requests.